# Мерцание экрана ноутбука даже в BIOS

Tags: linux, windows, железо, bios, ноутбук

Периодически начинает мерцать экран на ноутбуке при включении монитора ("screen flickering"). После отключения монитора на пару сек и включения снова перестает и не повторяется до следующего "горячего" включения (т.е. если сразу же ребутнуть, то повторится, но если включить после длительного неиспользования (на след. день), то не повторится). Воспроизводится как на винде, так и на линуксе. Также воспроизводится **без возможности остановки мерцания** (т.е. закрытие и открытие крышки не помогает) в меню UEFI (BIOS). Почитал, пишут, что раз в BIOS воспроизводится, то скорее всего hardware проблема. Нести в сервис или можно что-то ещё попробовать?

Comment: Не обязательно это может быть проблема с дровами и тп, это может быть проблема как с матрицей, так и с шлейфом. У самого данная проблема есть, понес в ремонт. Вот жду когда шлейф приедет

Comment: @OtetsValerian у вас давно моник работает? Это может из-за старости быть или только брак?

Comment: Данная проблема появилась через год после покупки в магазине. Думаю это связано было с тем, что я много его таскал с собой, из-за чего шлейф вышел из строя из-за частого открытия

Comment: Может быть просто из-за износа детали. Просто часто открывая скорее всего где-то перегибался. И работал адекватно потом только в определенном положение